# imageButton and OnClientClick

Tags: asp.net, imagebutton

I have a Imagebutton.

```
 <asp:ImageButton 
                            OnClientClick="alert('Du hast nun das Jetzt-Spielen-Feature aktiviert. \r\nEs zeigt anderen Nutzern von RPone in der Online-Liste hinter deinem Namen an, dass du jetzt gerne ein neues RPG beginnen würdest.\n\rDies hält 30 Minuten und deaktiviert sich automatisch, wenn du es nicht vorher deaktivierst.')"
                             OnClick="linkBtnNowPlay_Click"  ID="imgButtonNewPlay" ImageUrl="~/Images/star1.gif" runat="server" />
```

works like charm but

```
 <asp:ImageButton  OnClick="linkBtnNowPlay_Click"  ID="imgButtonNewPlay" ImageUrl="~/Images/star1.gif" runat="server" />
```

and

```
 imgButtonNewPlay.OnClientClick = "alert('test')";
```

on Serverside does not, why?
I must have it on server side because I must include an if statement before

Comment: try placing ; after alert('test') ; <--- because ASPX Engine adds its own __doPostBack after your alert statement. I have to hook it up to my VS to be able to answer the question. If you have this page hosted on internet, I can look at it and might be able to tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a semi-colon after alert();

ASPX Engine adds the call to __doPostBack() after your client code, without semi-colon; they are not separated well.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a javascript function directly like that from server side, you can add the following into your linkBtnNowPlay_Click method in code behind,

```
protected void linkBtnNowPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
Response.Write("<script>alert('test');</script>"); }
```

Comment: You can. And this is not what he is trying to do. He is intercepting the Postback to alert the user with a custom message before proceeding to postback.